# What extra activities can developers do to increase quality?

Tags: quality, development

We overestimated our project and are going to finish two weeks early.

Rather than fill in the extra time with additional features, management has directed the *development* team to use the extra time to ensure the highest possible quality code (Note: The QA team is not yet engaged.)

In what structured activities could the team engage in order to ensure the lowest possible defect rate and highest code quality?

Comment: Is there a reason why management doesn't want to get the QA team involved? Involving them will help to ensure that they understand the requirements and current design of the system to build appropriate requirement-based test cases at a system and acceptance level. Ideally, they should have been involved from the beginning since an unclear or incorrect requirement may have already caused issues that will take your two weeks to fix.

Comment: im amazed this is considered too broad. there is only one thing worth doing. write. more. tests.

Answer (score 2):

Do things that wouldn't geopardize the progress you already have.

- You can do some of the tasks the not yet functional QA team would do.
- You can proof-read documentation
- Do more testing
- Run a stress test to see how the app would behave under certain load conditions
- Create a road-map or revise the existing one
- Proof-read the app's strings and/or messages (that could include the internationalized ones)
- Explain code to other team members to promote colective ownership of code, or explain code to new members of the team.
- With the help of a graphic designer, make little adjusments (nothing big) to imperfections in the graphics (icons, buttons, etc.)
- Run a code beautifier (with conservative settings).

Comment: "Explain code ... ":  why not peer review ?

Comment: I miss here: code review and possible refactoring of code that could be "improved" applying SOLID principles. If there're unit and integration tests, should be doable. Otherwise is the right moment to implement these tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use retrospectives, then this is a good time to do one. Have the team review their own work and achievements and see where things could have gone better if they had other tools, processes, procedures, etc. See what can be tweeked.

I also like the idea of having team members sit with other groups in their work. Peer reviewing and pairing is always good for quality.

Last, it depends on the quality issues. A review of these and a brainstorming construction of ideas on how to imporve is always good. An offsite team event facilitated by a true Scrum Master or Agile Coach would definitely help with quality in a constructive way.